# Location of toString() Method of java.util.LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I am studying LinkedLists and wanted to check Java's implementation.

However, I have some questions.

I saw that I can print the contents of java.util.LinkedList.

Like this:

```
LinkedList ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();

ll.add(1);
ll.add(2);

System.out.println(ll);

// prints "[1, 2]"
```

However, I can't find the toString() method of LinkedList.

How does Java do that? How can it trigger the toString() method of every data type it has?

Answer (score 2):

The JavaDoc tells you which method is implement in whch parent class, for example the ones in [`AbstractCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#methods-inherited-from-class-java.util.AbstractCollection)

```
Methods declared in class java.util.AbstractCollection
containsAll, isEmpty, removeAll, retainAll, toString
```

---

The way is `LinkedList > AbstractSequentialList > AbstractList > AbstractCollection`

```
public class LinkedList<E> extends AbstractSequentialList<E> 
                           implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable

>> public abstract class AbstractSequentialList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {

>>> public abstract class AbstractList<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements List<E> {
```

---

You ends up with [`AbstractCollection.toString`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#L450) that iterates over each item to call their toString and join them with a comma, the whole enclosed in brackets

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (! it.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = it.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(',').append(' ');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of finding this, or you just knew it before?

Comment: @newbie It is written in the javadoc : https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#methods-inherited-from-class-java.util.AbstractCollection

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedList` inherits its implementation of `toString()` from `java.util.AbstractCollection`, which simply calls `toString` on the objects in the collection.  (All objects have it from `Object`, so it can just call it.)

Comment: Wow. How do you know that? I started from LinkedList, then AbstractSequentialList, then AbstractList, then AbstractCollection. How do you know that location?

Comment: If you look at the [api docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) you can see it lists of methods inherited from each parent class, e.g. "Methods declared in class java.util.AbstractCollection: [...] toString"

Comment: It's in the Javadoc. Below the Method Summary section is a list of the class hierarchy back to Object, showing where inherited and not overridden methods are located.

Comment: @newbie If you are using some IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ you can `Ctrl` + click on method you want to find source. So if you have code like `System.out.println(ll.toString());` `Ctrl+click` on `.toString()` part should redirect you to `public String toString() {...}` inside `java.util.AbstractCollection`.